# Parsing big XML file

Tags: php, xml

I've checked many Questions and I didn't get answer.

I have a big XML file that I need to parse. Currently I am parsing it with **XMLReader**. It worked good until I started to inserting it into SQL db. If I only echo parse the xml it works fine , if I'm inserting it I get ***504 Gateway Time-out*** error. Here is sample of my code:

Where I parse xml:

```
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open(APP_PATH_OWA."/trnUpload/TRNavteraData.xml");

while($xml->read()){
 //get products
 if($xml->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $xml->localName == 'table'){    
    $product = array();
 }

 if($xml->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $xml->localName == 'ident'){
    $xml->read();
    $product['id'] = $xml->value;
 }
    ...
```

Foreach:

```
foreach($products as $product){
  ...
 $productTitle = $product['title'];
 $productID = $product['id'];
 $productImageUrl = "http://www.example.com/logo.png";
 $productAttrHtml = $product['computed'];

 // after that I'm inserting those data using ZEND framework.
```

XML file is about 300k+ lines.

Whole php function: http://pastebin.com/S8A5Rdjw

Comment: Since the problem appeared when you started to insert things into your DB, it might be interesting to share that part of the code. How long does it take without the DB process ?

Comment: Im sharing it in a min, It doesn't take really long without DB process. And I figured one more thing, After I get 504 Gateway Time-out, I can't access any part of my site, the whole server timeout I think. After few mins(15-20) server start running normally and articles from XML are stored in db. http://pastebin.com/S8A5Rdjw - here is my function.

Comment: Are you using Apache or NGINX? Have you tried increasing php timeout limit? if not, try putting `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of your script.

Comment: I've already changed timeout limit, I'm using NGINX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializing the process will decrease the memory consumption but increase the runtime. But I don't think time is the problem here.

You might just block the access to the database (table) with to many insert statements.

Some tips:

1. Using a framework for database imports might be really slow if that kind of action is not supported by the framework. Try to avoid database abstractions for this.
2. Make sure to use mass inserts. Most databases allow to insert several records at once one way or another. This reduces the database calls. (Of course in increases the needed memory so you will have to find a balance.)
3. Check that the inserts do not block the selects. Depends on the database and in case of MySQL on the table handler.
4. Insert into a separate table and rename the tables after that.
5. Generate a file and use the databases command line client to import it.